# Excel: Is there a way to match Two Columns while matching a third

Tags: excel, search, format, match

Column B & C's values match each other and Column ID & A's values match each other (as in the codes are the same customer). Column A & B contain the same values but in a different order, is it possible to match those values, allowing all the columns to match?

E.g

```
---ID---|---A------|------B---|----C---|---D---|         
 23-------AB12------BA13---------K00     
 12-------BA13------BC33---------K01    
 45-------AC31------AB12---------K02      
 65-------BC33------CC31---------K03      
 11-------AA22------CB21---------K04                
 02-------CB21------AC31---------K05          
 57-------CC31------AA22---------K06
```

---

Ideally the first row should be:

```
|  ID  |   A   |   B   |   C   |  D  |
   23     AB12    AB12    K02
```

---

Can this be done on a large spreadsheet 10,000+ ?

Comment: Move Columns B and C over a few coloums then use vlookup.

Comment: Okay so, =vlookup(match, A2;B:B) something like that?  =IF(ISNA(MATCH(B2,C:C,0)),"",INDEX(C:C,MATCH(B2,C:C,0)))

Comment: No google VLOOKUP Excel and you will get many tutorials on how to use the function.

Comment: A few things on your question, as you are new to SO: It would help to provide sample data in some way that is straighforward for use to use -after you're trying to get help, and we're trying to help you. I don't want to mess around with poorly structured sample data.

Also, this question could fairly easily be answered through some googling - maybe 30 minutes if you're fairly new to Excel, but still... If that doesn't work then sure, come to SO & ask away.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to change the order of your columns to do that, just use INDEX(MATCH()) instead of vlookup - I'm not quite sure why vlookup is even a thing to be honest.

But first, if you work on a large dataset and maybe you'll have to revisit things later, let's work smartly and NAME OUR RANGES instead of using dirty $A$5 notations.

SO here's our reduced dataset:

[image]

Let's select the whole of the columns containing data, like so, and in the upper left corner we're going to name it "col_B" (or whatever else you fancy):

[image]

Do that for all the columns you'll use.

You can now set a separate section (or another worksheet completely since you have lots of data) to re-order your dataset. Like so. We're going to use col_A as our reference, so let's already populate it (just copy-past I guess) with your source data:

[image]

In our final result, we want column B to be the same as column A. So let's just write that formula in our first cell of column B, and increment that all the way to the end:

[image]

You now want col C to be whatever value that correspond to each col B value in your old table - we're going to use Index(MatchT)) like so:
[image]

In english this means:

INDEX(COL_TO_RETURN, MATCH(COL_TO_SEARCH_FOR_VALUE, VALUE_TO_SEARCH, 0))

In other words, it will return the corresponding value for col_C (of the source data, so the column you have previously named). It will take the value in D3 (your new sheet's column B) as the thing to search for. It will search for that D3 value inside col_B, the range that you have named so in your source data. "0" just means you want an exact match.

The fact that we named our columns just makes them easier to reference -you could do without but it's a lot cleaner.

Much, much better would be to work with table & structured notation, but that's abit more of a stretch so let's stop it here. The result is this:

[image]

Apply the same logic for your ID column & you're done.

If you like the answer, please accept it! (the check mark next to the post)

Comment: I disagree, and I certainly don't think it's worth a downvote. Vlookup is just a poorly conceived formula in general. Just google "index-match vs vlookup" & learn.

I made it super detailed because the OP obviously doesn't have a lot of experience with Excel. Most of what I would do you'd still need to do with your vlookup. Basically with both you need the same things at a minimum - I just think that named range >> than dirty fixed ranges.

Are you going to tell me you consider fixed range notation & vlookup best pratices to promote?

Comment: I just think that if just saying "dude, your question sucks" is unlikely to change much. Nor is just ignoring it. I could have passed on it, as you did. I just think that giving someone a bit of help, THEN commenting on how/what to do differently is more likely to get your point accross. We agree on the question - just have different ways to deal with it.

No didn't mean to put that on document - that guy may not be an excel guru but surely he's smart to get what's a named range & how to use index-match. So why would I push poor practices on him still?